# MFC CChildView::OnPaint how to draw unfilled circle

Tags: c++, mfc

I am fairly family with writing MFC apps with modest graphics but this has me stuck :-(
How do I draw and unfilled circle/ellipse please?
From my experience I draw a circle using the Ellipse function and the Ellipse function uses a pen object for the circle and a brush object to fill the circle.
But I want to draw nine overlapping circles, but only the edge/circumference of the circles but not the body if you see what I mean. basically something that looks like a venn diagram.

Many thanks in advance imk

Comment: Select a null brush into the device context. As in `myCD.SelectStockObject(NULL_BRUSH)`

Comment: Work a treat, many thanks

Comment: You'll probably want to read up on [device contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/device-contexts).